# Advice for logging in an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

My current project structure is made to do logging of exceptions and such into the database instead of log files.

In order to log down details, it goes through web services of another project (logToDBService).
So I'm wondering that if by chance the web service fails, I will not be able to log down new message.
To counter this, for those failed logs, I thought of logging it down into csv so it can be uploaded into the database manually.

And for this to handled by the system without configuring additional permission, what I can think of at the moment is to introduce a web service (logToCSVService) directly in the same asp.net application, so when the logging at the logToDBService fails, it execute logToCSVService.

Comment: I would recommend removing your logging and instead implement ASP.NET Health Monitoring.

Comment: I hope you have a catchall in your logging code in case of connectivity issues.

Comment: @Novikov: that wouldn't be necessary if he used Health Monitoring. It would be the catch-all.

Comment: @John, not my call to have logging removed. We have a module for administrator to view the error log when exception occurs. And users would definitely prefer if the exception is in the web itself.

Comment: @Novikov: I not sure what you meant by catchall, but for all methods calling the web service, it will have a try catch. webservice used is WCF, so I am throwing fault exception if caught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use log4net.  It can handle database, files, email etc.

Comment: Log4Net is better than having a custom service do the writing to a database.  Much more reliable.   It allows you to write to multiple destinations simultaneously

Comment: I believed that it is a dll file right? If so I can take a look at it, given that Narean mention that it can log simultaneously. But is it customizable for the values and my database columns?

Comment: Yes to all the above.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html.  Also, many people use Common Logging (http://commons.apache.org/logging/) as an facade so that differing logging implementations can be used,

Comment: I think I go with just that cause it will definitely be more easier to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We've used ELMAH for logging errors to a database and also to an email address as a backup. It works quite well and has a lot of developers supporting it. Check out more about ELMAH here:
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: nice thing to have, especially the part for email. Will need that for 1 of the modules. But judging that it is classified in 32 bits and 64 bits, can I assume that it is more of a exe file that I need to install. My current application is totally based in web, meaning no installation of other products. And also have to be microsoft based